# Paypal integration with java package error

Tags: java, payment-gateway

> com.paypal.sdk.core.nvp.NVPDecoder
>   package cannot be resolved

Is there any jar files is available?

Comment: Is this class not in the [SDK](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks) ?

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote Ranjith. The PayPal SDK is a mess (!!!) and the documentation and samples are usually not consistent with the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Download the **full** PayPal SDK for Java [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Java_NVP_SDK.zip).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you havent imported the jar file to your workspace incorrectly. Remove it and re-add it.

If you want to get the most out of this site you will need to write a detailed question outlining clearly  what is wrong. Have a look at the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)